# How to add horizontaly aligned static text on the Y axis of a Telerik chart

Tags: telerik, silverlight-5.0, radchart

I have a telerik RadCartesianChart and i just want to add horizontaly aligned static text on the Y axis of the chart.

Below is the chart xaml`

```
         <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                <telerik:LinearAxis Minimum="-10" Maximum="100" MajorStep="10" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="9" ShowLabels="True" LabelFitMode="None">
                </telerik:LinearAxis>
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>

            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                <telerik:LinearAxis Minimum="1" Maximum="100" MajorStep="10" ShowLabels="True" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="9" >
                </telerik:LinearAxis>
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>

            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>
                <telerik:CartesianChartGrid MajorLinesVisibility="XY">
                    <telerik:CartesianChartGrid.MajorXLineStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Line">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#868686"/>
                        </Style>
                    </telerik:CartesianChartGrid.MajorXLineStyle>
                    <telerik:CartesianChartGrid.MajorYLineStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Line">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#868686"/>
                        </Style>
                    </telerik:CartesianChartGrid.MajorYLineStyle>
                </telerik:CartesianChartGrid>
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Grid>

            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>

                <telerik:ScatterPointSeries Cursor="Arrow" DisplayName="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ShowLabels="True" >
                    <telerik:ScatterPointSeries.XValueBinding>
                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding  PropertyName="X" ></telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding>
                    </telerik:ScatterPointSeries.XValueBinding>

                    <telerik:ScatterPointSeries.YValueBinding>
                        <telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Y"></telerik:PropertyNameDataPointBinding>
                    </telerik:ScatterPointSeries.YValueBinding>

                    <telerik:ScatterPointSeries.LabelDefinitions>
                        <telerik:ChartSeriesLabelDefinition HorizontalAlignment="Center" Strategy="{StaticResource strategy}">

                        </telerik:ChartSeriesLabelDefinition>

                    </telerik:ScatterPointSeries.LabelDefinitions>
                </telerik:ScatterPointSeries>

                <!--ScatterAreaSeries-->
                <telerik:ScatterAreaSeries XValueBinding="X"  YValueBinding="Y"   ZIndex="-200" Fill="Red" ShowLabels="True">
                    <telerik:ScatterAreaSeries.DataPoints>
                        <telerik:ScatterDataPoint XValue="0" YValue="200"/>
                        <telerik:ScatterDataPoint XValue="200" YValue="0"/>
                    </telerik:ScatterAreaSeries.DataPoints>
                </telerik:ScatterAreaSeries>

                <telerik:ScatterAreaSeries XValueBinding="X"  YValueBinding="Y"   ZIndex="-200"  Fill="Yellow" ShowLabels="True">
                    <telerik:ScatterAreaSeries.DataPoints>
                        <telerik:ScatterDataPoint XValue="0" YValue="140"/>
                        <telerik:ScatterDataPoint XValue="140" YValue="0"/>
                    </telerik:ScatterAreaSeries.DataPoints>
                  </telerik:ScatterAreaSeries>

                <telerik:ScatterAreaSeries XValueBinding="X" YValueBinding="Y"   ZIndex="-200" Fill="Green" ShowLabels="True">
                    <telerik:ScatterAreaSeries.DataPoints>
                        <telerik:ScatterDataPoint XValue="0" YValue="90" Label="Category" />
                        <telerik:ScatterDataPoint XValue="90" YValue="0"/>
                    </telerik:ScatterAreaSeries.DataPoints>
                    <telerik:ScatterAreaSeries.LegendSettings>
                        <telerik:SeriesLegendSettings   Title="Low                       Moderate               High               Significant               Critical" />
                    </telerik:ScatterAreaSeries.LegendSettings>
                    </telerik:ScatterAreaSeries>
                </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>

        </telerik:RadCartesianChart>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all i needed was setting the Title property

```
  <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                <telerik:LinearAxis Minimum="-10" Maximum="100" MajorStep="10" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="9" ShowLabels="True" LabelFitMode="None" Title="This is all i needed to set">
                </telerik:LinearAxis>
               </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
```